# How to use size classes and autolayout in storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am trying to use size classes and Autolayout in storyboard.

//So sorry that I cant post images for not enough reputaitons.

**It seems that I've uploaded my photo successfully**, and it is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVg8p.png) now. The white area is the UIView, and only a UILable as its subview, the size class is wCompact and hRegular.

I set a `UIView` below the `UINavigationBar`, and then add a `UILabel` on the view.
To show this on the all the iphone simulator, I user the wCompact and hRegular size classes.

I want the label to be set in the center of the screen.  So I set a constrains for the label that Align horizontal center in container.

But I can't see anything on the simulator, even the `UIView` disappears.

Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: did you applied any constraints on UIView too?

Comment: @WaqasRaja No, just a constrains for the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the height of your UIView changes? Try putting constraints to your UIView too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found such a stupid mistake.
I have't set the contrains for the UIView, so it's covered by the navigationBar...this will not happen on Xcode5, for the View is just below the UINavigationBar in the storyboard.

I tried log the UIView's frame, but I did that in the viewdidLoad method, then I got a wrong frame, because the UIView instance in the storyboard hasn't be init at that time...I should do that in the viewDidAppear method...

Tks for your answers.